# Putting drawables in front of one another causes dramatic used memory increase

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, memory, memory-management

Usual memory footprint of my app is around 20MB. However, when I put drawables one in front of the other (for the sake of animating the each individual element)...

[image]

*There are actually two drawables in this picture: the green base and the pin (with its shadow)*

...my memory usage goes up by ~40MB!The layout is using xhdpi drawables, which have around 2.1MB in total. The layout of these drawables is:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.2">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/serbia"
            android:src="@drawable/serbia"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/pin"
            android:src="@drawable/pin"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

What is causing such sudden memory increase? Is there a way to bypass such practice, but still be able to animate each part of the image separately?

Note that I still have to properly align these elements (the pin isn't in the center of the layout), because the right edge of the shadow is cropped to the shape of the base)

Answer (score 1):

The pin and the shadow may be small but the view size is the same as the parent as you layout them so the bigger one  (the parent) sets the size of all them three buffers for painting. So the biggest size multiplied by 3 (or four, I donno how actually the container paints itself) is the memory used. And by biggest I mean biggest in screen format, not in the file compressed.

Best thing to do could be to paint them yourself or stack them up using a FrameLayout and then setting x and y possition... Donno right now if u can set thrm in the xml directly but, if not, set them in code elsewhere.

Comment: Okay, do you have any tips on how to properly align them? They need to be perfectly aligned on every screen size...

Comment: actually you can stack them up with the FrameLayout as I said before and then, apply the wrap_content size to the red pin but with centered position and such. But NOTICE the wrap_content. If you set the size to be the parent size, the component will eat out the device memory again.

Comment: if u position them by code, just `newx = parentWidth / 2 - width / 2`. Same for `y`. It will center an image in parent coordinates.

Comment: I'm still clueless... where do I "set the x and y position"? I transformed my drawables so that now I use just two: pin and the shadow, and the base. However, I still need to align the pin to the base...

Comment: Align? is´nt it in the center of the parent? `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

Comment: Please, provide more info

Comment: one of the zillion solutions could be to have the pin and the shadow in the same image because there is no need for them to be in different images and position them knowingly the width of the red pin and such. I don´t get what `the right edge of the shadow is cropped to the shape of the base` means because, for me, the base is square as it looks and will be cropped down. But, if you mean that the island shore is cropping the shaddow, it also can be solved changing the order layers are painted on the image and transparency: green square, pin&shadow, transparent island and blue sea

Comment: **note** I KNOW Serbia is not an island... was a way of explaining this thing